# Is there a way to get the number of lines of a buffer in Vim Script?

Tags: vim

Is there a way to get just the number of lines in a Vim buffer, not necessarily the current one?

With `line('$')` one can get the number of the last line of the current buffer, hence the line amount. With `getbufline({expr}, 1 , '$')` one can get a list of line strings of a buffer given by `{expr}`, the list size being then, the number of lines.

Using `getbufline` has the overhead of copying an entire file in memory just to get the number of lines it contains. `line` does the job, but works only for current buffer.

This is supposed to be done from script, not interactively and with minimal overhead as with `line('$')` if possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If vim is compiled with python support and is not older then 7.3.569 you can use

```
python import vim
let numlines=pyeval('len(vim.buffers['.({expr}-1).'])')
```

. With older vims with python support you can use

```
python import vim
python vim.command('let numlines='+str(len(vim.buffers[int(vim.eval('{expr}'))-1])))
```

. Testing revealed that for 11 MiB log file the first solution is 209 times faster then `len(getbufline({expr}, 1, '$'))` (0.000211 vs 0.044122 seconds). Note that buffers in `vim.buffers` are indexed starting with zero, not with one.

Comment: out of curiosity, how did you profiled and obtained the timings?

Comment: @chico Generally profiling is described in `:h :profile`. But for one-liners there is simpler approach: `let rt=reltime() | {do action} | echom reltimestr(reltime(rt))`.

Comment: Please note that this does not work if the buffer is not loaded into memory. For example, immediately after `vi a.txt b.txt`, `a.txt` is loaded and ready for editing. Loading `b.txt` will be postponed until the buffer is first switched to.

Answer (score 0):

Since Vim 8.1.1967 (Sept 2019) you can pass window ID to `line()` as second argument. So now it is simply:

```
line('$', bufwinid(bufnr))
```

where `bufnr` is the buffer number.